# Hi, How can I check which page is being loaded in Angular other than by url

Tags: html, angular, selector

In the app.component.html ,I am checking which page is  being loaded
other than by url. If it is landing page then  insert image1 else for other pages insert
image2.

```
<ng-container *ngif= "!app-home;then restOfThePages;else landingPage">
</ng-container>

<ng-template> #landingPage
<Image1 class ="....">
</ng-template>

<ng-template  #restOfThePages>
<Image2 class ="....">
</ng-template>
```

Comment: What is a condition for app-home in component file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a service which you inject and set a boolean `isLandingPage` in the constructor of the landingComponent to true, the other components set it to false

Then in appcomponent get that boolean value and use *ngIf in the template to display the correct image

Comment: How can I   check which component /page is loading through the service.(but not with loading url)

Comment: Add a public property string to the service called currenpage and set it in the individual components